# Composer installation order

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

Is it possible to set the installation order?

Currently I'm using Doctrine module that requires `ext-mongo` to be installed, but as I'm using the newer php version (7.0) I have `mongodb` installed instead. There's a `alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter` package that resolves installation problems. But there's one problem - Composer is trying to install Doctrine modules first, so that installation fails.

Currently I have to resolve this problem manually, but I can't do it any more as I'm going to pack my environment to a Docker image to let it be automatically deployed later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs of alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter

"

```
$ composer require alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter
```

If your project already has a dependency on ext-mongo, the command above may not work. This is due to a bug in composer, see https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5030

To fix this, you can use the --ignore-platform-reqs switch when running the above command, or when running composer update with no composer.lock file present."

Comment: Thanks @Hexagon, '--ignore-platform-reqs' really helped. Of course it's not a good solution, but it seems that it is only one decision without hardcoding.